# Identity having to do with weak derivative

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

For $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$, let $(a,b) = G \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval in the real numbers.
Show that there exists no $v \in L^2(G)$ and no $y \in G$ such that $$ \int_G v \varphi \text{d}x  = \varphi(y) $$ 
holds for all test functions $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0(G) $.

Since I don't have a mathematics background I have trouble with this kind of problems. Can someone give me a generous hint how one can solve such a (and particularly this) problem?

Comment: You are right, its not necessary for this problem. I will edit my question.

Comment: Moreover, you can fix some $x$. Why all the $x_i$'s?

Comment: I can only give the hint to use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Argue by contradiction that such $v,y$ exist. By Cauchy-Schwarz, the set $$A=\{ \varphi (y) : \varphi \in C^{\infty}_0 (G), ||\varphi||_2 \le 1\}$$ is bounded (it is contained in the interval $(-||v||_2, ||v||_2)$).

Now, try to construct some sequence $\{ \varphi_n \}_{n \ge 1}$ of bell-shaped smooth functions with compact support  satisfying:

1. $||\varphi_n||_2 \le 1$ for all $n$
2. the support of $\varphi_n$ becomes thinner and thinner around $y$ (for example, it is contained in $(y-1/n^2, y +1/n^2)$)
3. $\varphi_n (y) \to + \infty$

This will contradict the boundedness of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I fear you need to be even more generous with me. How do you get from $\int_G v \varphi \text{d}x  = \varphi(y)$ to set A and the fact that its bounded in the interval $(-||v||_2, ||v||_2)$?

Comment: Well, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for all $||\varphi||_2 \le 1$, $$|\varphi(y)|= \left| \int v \varphi \right| \le \int |v \varphi| \le ||v||_2||\varphi||_2 \le ||v||_2$$

Comment: Got that. And I think I understand the rest of your proof. Last question: Does an explicit function with these properties exist? Or do I just describe it as a set of such bell shaped smooth functions?

Comment: @mwater Usually one uses the smooth function $$u(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} & x \in (-1,1) \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{matrix} \right.$$ So you need $\varphi_n(x) = n \phi (n^2(x-y))$

Comment: We have that: $$E(t,x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 
\frac{e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{(2 \sqrt{\pi t})^n} &, t>0 \\ \\ 
0 &, t \leq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: I want to show that $\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E=\delta(t,x) $.

So it suffices to show that  $\langle \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E, \phi \rangle=\phi(0,0)$.

I have shown so far that $\langle \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{t}}-\Delta E, \phi \rangle=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(2 \sqrt{\pi \epsilon})^n} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4 \epsilon}} \phi(\epsilon,x) dx $

How could we continue? @Crostul

Comment: @Evinda I have no idea: this deserves a new question.